# Copy table data to clipboard with java

Tags: java, swing, copy-paste

I generate some data that I want to be able to copy to clipboard, either by using mouse to select the information, or by clicking a button to copy the data to a clipboard. How do i copy the dataset variables content to clipboard?

```
private DefaultCategoryDataset createDataSetHenvendelser(Vector<CallQueue> data, boolean total) {
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

    for (CallQueue col : data) {
        dataset.addValue(col.getCallSum().getCalls(), "Telefoniske henvendelser", col.getPeriod());
        dataset.addValue(col.getOTBOpgaver().getCalls(), "Overtræksopgaver", col.getPeriod());
    }

    if (total)
        for (CallQueue col : data) {
            double sum = 
                         col.getPrivatcentre().getCalls() 


            dataset.addValue(sum, "Total", col.getPeriod());
        }

    return dataset;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What are you having troubles with?

Comment: I don't know how to copy this data, I have looked around and only found examples of copying strings of text to clipboard, but not of the specific data type I work with.

Comment: Clipboard code is specific to the GUI system you are using - so which one is it (SWT, JavaFX, Swing/AWT, ....)?

Comment: You will have to convert your data to a string first, put it on the clipboard and then you are able to paste it somewhere.

Comment: I use Swing/AWT, and thanks @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker that helps me closer to solving it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to replace the DB.